Как изменить класс у title в виджете wordpress?
Зарегистрировал в function.php раздел виджетов и поставил нужные мне классы в теге title.
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'band_digital_widgets_init' );
function band_digital_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => esc_html__('Сайдбар блога', 'band_digital'),
    'id'   => "sidebar-blog",
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</section>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title mb-3">',
    'after_title'   => "</h3>\n"
));
}

вывел сайдбар
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-blog' ) ) : ?>
 <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-blog' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

в итоге он мне не проставляет в теге title нужный класс, а меняет на свой.
<section id="block-6" class="sidebar-widget widget_block">
 <div class="wp-block-group"><div class="wp-block-group__inner-container is-layout-constrained 
  wp-block-group-is-layout-constrained">
  <h5 class="wp-block-heading">О нас</h5>
  <p>Тут какой то текст</p>
 </div></div>
</section>

быть может я как-то не правильно добавляю виджет заголовка?


У Вас явно что-то не так, в before_title у Вас открывающий h3, в after_title закрывающий h2, а в выводе вообще h5.

А, спасибо за поправку, во время того как вставлял на сайт случайно видимо удалил и вставил другую цифру

в любом случае, он все равно класс таким образом не подставляет, думаю уже может попробовать через функцию фильтра заменить класс вордпресса

Скорее всего потому что Вы используете виджет на основе гутенберг блока

А есть какой-то вариант это пофиксить? Не подключая классический стиль виджетов. Так как, допустим, условно заказчик захотел поменять сайдбар, удалил все блоки и решил их заново настроить.

Пофиксить что? Вы создаете заголовок при помощи Gutenberg блока заголовка)
